# Why does redrawing my image not work properly?

Tags: javascript, html

You helped me get the draw function work properly. Here's the complete program, which works perfectly until the "draw" button is clicked. Instead of drawing a new image, the entire window vanishes. Any help greatly appreciated!

This code is formatted as instructed, 4 spaces per tab. I don't know any more details to add.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Digital Holograms</title>
            <style>
                div {
                    float: left;
                    height: 580px;
                    width:  500px;;
                    padding: 0 10px;
                }
                #column1 {
                    background-color: #FFFFFF;
                }
                #column2 {
                    background-color: #FFFFFF;
                    width: 500px
                }
      
            </style> 
    </head>
  
    <body>
        <div id="column1">    
        
            <canvas id="my-canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas> 
        
            <script>
                let selFun = 0  // selected function to draw
                                // user may change this by selection box
                let canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas')
                let context = canvas.getContext('2d')
                    context.fillStyle = 'black'
             
                function draw(n) {              
                    let contourInterval = 1500
                    let contourWidth = 500
                    let fsize = 1000
                    let x0 = fsize / 2
                    let y0 = fsize / 2

                    for (j = 0, y = -y0; j < fsize; j++, y++) {
                        for (i = 0, x = -x0; i < fsize; i++, x++) {
                            let fun = 0     
                            switch(n) {
                            case 0:
                                fun = (x*x + y*y)
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                fun = (x*x - y*y)                       
                                break;      
                            default:
                                fun = (x*x + y*y)
                            }
                            if (Math.abs(fun % contourInterval) < contourWidth) {
                                context.fillRect(x+x0/2, y+y0/2, 1, 1)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    document.write('<h4 style="text-align: center;">Hologram of z = x&#x00B2 + y&#x00B2</h4>');     
                }
                
                draw(selFun)

                function getSelection() {
                    let selFun = document.getElementById("selectFunction").value
                    //document.write(selFun)
                }                       
            </script>
    
            <h3>To view other holograms:</br>Select a function, then press draw</h3>

            <select id="selectFunction" onchange="getSelection()">
            <option value=0>z = x&#x00B2 + y&#x00B2</option>
            <option value=1>z = x&#x00B2 - y&#x00B2</option>
            </select>
            
            <button type = "button";
                onclick = draw(selFun)>Draw</button>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There a several glitches that are preventing this code working as intended.

**1) The loss of content on button press**

This is a result of an incorrect use of `document.write()` (which can only be effectively used by inline scripts to inset text as the page is loading. Running it on a loaded page causes `document.open()` to be executed, clearing the existing document. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

The correct way to update information on the page is to change the `innerText` or `innerHTML` of an existing element, or insert a new element with the required text.

In my snippet I added the `h4` tag, with an id of `updatedTitle`, to the html (initially with no content, which will be added by the script):

```
<h4 id="updatedTitle" style="text-align: center;"></h4>
```

The `innerText` of the tag is added by the last line of the draw() function:

```
document.getElementById("updatedTitle").innerText = `Hologram of ${equation}`;
```

Note, the template literal `${equation}`, this was used to allow the equation to be updated when a new option is drawn, by fetching the markup for the equation from the element (shown later).

**2) Drop Down changes not registering**
After correcting point 1), there was still a problem: pressing the draw button failed to render a new graph. After some investigation with `console.log()`s at various parts of the execution cycle I determined that the `onchange` of the dropdown element was not being received by the javascript.

The reason for this turned out to be a case of very bad luck - the choice of the function name intended to handle the change: `getSelection`. It turns out that `getSelection` is a built-in method of the `Window` object and seemingly cannot be used as a user function name.

Changing the function name to `readSelection()` cured this problem;

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)

**3) Button onclick event argument not accessible**

The button's onlick event calls the `draw()` function, and attempts to send `selFun` as an argument. As written, `selFun` is not accessible from the element.

Instead, the onlick was changed to simply call the `draw()` function without any argument.

`selFun` is declared, and assigned with 0, in the global scope of the script and so is accessible from function in the script. Thus the argument `n` used in the `switch` block of the `draw()` function can be replaced directly with `selFun` (and `n` also deleted from the function parameter):

**4) modification to readSelection()**
The original values of the option list items were 0 and 1, entered as (unquotted) numbers in the markup. Although this is allowed, the 0 and 1 are converted to strings when the `value` attribute is read regardless of whether they were quotted or not (much like the contents of a text `input` field). Javascript is good at coercing numbers from digit characters but I was getting a bug where `selFun` was not being read properly for the case statement. Formally setting `selFun` to an integer value cured this:

```
selFun = parseInt(document.getElementById("selectFunction").value);
```

Since `readSelection` is invoked each time the drop down changes, it is also the place to keep track of which equation should be used in the label on next draw. Hence the following line was included in the function:

```
equation = document.getElementById("selectFunction").children[selFun].innerText;
```

with `equation` being declared (and set to the dropdown initial state) in the global scope of the script, to be read and used to form a label, as discussed in 1) above.

**5) Draw only working for first change of equation**

Once the above changes were made, changing the dropdown and pressing the button resulted in the new equation being rendered. However, subsequent changes and attempts to draw did not appear to do much.

This was because the second equation was being drawn on top of the first and, once both equations were drawm further drawing didn's show any change.

The solution was to include a standard clear step at the start of the `draw()` function:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

**6) Element accessibility**
The entire script was moved to the foot of the html to allow all elements to load before running the script, this prevented some errors where the js was trying to access elements that did not yet exist.

The programme seems to work as intended now. I don't understand anything about the equation plots but they are most impressive and, should you add more to it in future, perhaps you will comment back here so I can have a look!

Working snippet:

```js
let selFun = 0
let equation = document.getElementById("selectFunction").children[selFun].innerHTML; // to be used to update graph label;

let canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = 'black';
             
function draw() {

  // clear canvas'
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         
  let contourInterval = 1500;
  let contourWidth = 500;
  let fsize = 1000;
  let x0 = fsize / 2
  let y0 = fsize / 2

  for (j = 0, y = -y0; j < fsize; j++, y++) {
    for (i = 0, x = -x0; i < fsize; i++, x++) {
      let fun = 0  
                            
      switch(selFun) {
        case 0:
          fun = (x*x + y*y);
          break;
        case 1:
          fun = (x*x - y*y);                     
          break;      
        default:
          fun = (x*x + y*y);
      } // end switch

      if (Math.abs(fun % contourInterval) < contourWidth) {
        context.fillRect(x+x0/2, y+y0/2, 1, 1)
      } // end if;
    } // next i;
  } // next j;

  const titleH4 = document.getElementById("updatedTitle");
  document.getElementById("updatedTitle").innerText = `Hologram of ${equation}`;

} // end draw;
                
draw();

function readSelection() {                   
 selFun = parseInt(document.getElementById("selectFunction").value);
 equation = document.getElementById("selectFunction").children[selFun].innerText;
} // end readSelection function;
```

```css
div {
  float: left;
  height: 580px;
  width:  500px;;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#column1 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#column2 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 500px
}
select {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: cyan;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="column1">    
        
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    
<h3>To view other holograms:</br>Select a function, then press draw</h3>

<select id="selectFunction" onchange="readSelection()">
  <option value="0">z = x&#x00B2 + y&#x00B2</option>
  <option value="1">z = x&#x00B2 - y&#x00B2</option>
</select>

<button type = "button" onclick="draw()">Draw</button> 
   
<h4 id="updatedTitle" style="text-align: center;"></h4>

</div>
```

**edit**
Regarding the appearance of the dropdown and button - they can be styled much like any other html element. I've added some arbitrary changes to their apperance by adding rules for `select` and `button` elements to the css. The elements can be given a class name if more specific styling is needed without affecting other elements of the same kind.

Comment: How can I possibly thank you enough?! This is amazing. I will post my final program for you to enjoy. The holograms exhibit spatial aliasing, which explains the bizarre patterns that appear once the contour lines become so thin that they pass between the pixels of the display. It shows the classical problem of trying to display a continuous function in a discrete environment.

Comment: My only remaining issue is making the selection box and the button larger. I've searched the web for how to do this, but so far have not found a suitable solution. Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Glad it helped. I've made an edit to address the appearance of the dropdown and button - most aspects of them can be styled as for any other elements. regarding 'thanks', the usual way is by accepting an answer (if it is correct and helped you solve your problem) and/or by upvoting helpful comments. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code is trying to do but when the button is pressed you are updating the source completely.

Here is that bad code :)

```js
 document.write('<h4 style="text-align: center;">Hologram of z = x&#x00B2 + y&#x00B2</h4>');
```

Add it inside a div instead of writing it to the whole document.

```js
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = 'your codes';
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It doesn't even explain why the code is "bad". Try asking the OP questions in the comments first in order to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @Cully It was said by the OP that the page was completely empty. I also stated that this problem is from the bad code above. Probably a mistake made in absentia...

Comment: Riga is correct. When I move that line out of the draw function, the draw button no longer wipes out the window -- but it doesn't update the image either.

Comment: Problem solved, I had double quotes in my getElementByID, but single quotes are correct! Many thanks to all!